# Showing Items from Room with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I am trying to show items from my room database with JetPack Compose like in [this example](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5).

My Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "trains")
data class TrainSearch(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    override var id: Long = 0L,
    var type: TrainType = TrainType.ICE,
    var number: String = "",
    override var name: String? = null
) : Listable {}
```

My Repository:

```
class ListableRepositoryImpl(private val trainSearchDao: TrainSearchDao) : ListableRepository {
    override fun fetchAllItems(): Flow<TrainSearch> {
        return trainSearchDao.getAllTrainSearches()
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
class FavListViewModel(private val homeRepo: ListableRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val savedItems = homeRepo.fetchAllItems()
}
```

My Compose Function:

```
(...)
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
(...)

fun FavListScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    favListViewModel: FavListViewModel = koinViewModel()
) {

    val savedItems:List<TrainSearch> by favListViewModel.savedItems.collectAsState(initial = emptyList<TrainSearch>())
(...)
```

But I am getting the Error Message, that `getValue` is not suitable. And I have no Idea why. :(
[image: Error Message in Android Studio]

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of debugging and logging sessions. I was using the wrong type `Flow<TrainSearch>`. In the example the Author uses `typealias Books = List<Book>`. This was misleading me. I had to use `Flow<List<TrainSearch>>`.